# Cannot read property of undefined (react)

Tags: reactjs, this

I'm thinking this has something to do with "this", but I can't quite figure it out.  I'm receiving an error that title is undefined and states the error stems from my Edit.js file.  However, no error displayed until I attempted this.setState({ recipes: updateRecipe});

**App.js**

```
constructor() {
  super();
  this.titleChange = this.titleChange.bind(this);
  //get initial state//
  this.state = {
    recipes: {
      recipe1: {
        title: 'Pacific Halibut',
        time: 17,
        description: 'the best halibut ever',
        ingredient: ['halibut', "oil", "salt", "pepper", "kale"],
        instruction: ['preheat oven at 350', 'sprinkle seasonings on fish', 'place foil on baking sheet', 'bake for 17 minutes']
      },
      recipe2: {
        title: 'Cookies',
        time: 12,
        description: 'yummy cookies',
        ingredient: ['cookie dough', 'chocolate chips', 'flour', 'butter', 'sugar'],
        instruction: ['preheat oven at 350', 'mix ingreients together in a bowl', 'place a teaspoon of dough on a baking sheet one inch apart', 'bake for 12 minutes']
      }
    }
  }
}

titleChange = (id) => (e) => {
  const updateRecipe = Object.keys(recipes).map((recipe, sidx) => {
    const target = e.target;
    const name = target.name;
    const value = target.value;
    const recipes = {...this.state.recipes};
    if (id !== sidx) return recipe;
      return { ...recipe, [name]: value};
    });
  console.log(updateRecipe);
  this.setState({ recipes: updateRecipe});
}
```

**Edit.js**

```
render(){
  var id = (this.props.match.params.id);

  return(
    <input type="text" className="add-input" name="title" value={this.props.recipes[id].title} onChange={this.props.titleChange(id)}></input>
}
```

Thanks for the help.

Comment: can you post your edit component

Comment: Are you passing all the necessary `props` to the Edit component? It would be helpful to see the full components.

Answer (score 1):

In this line you are iterating `recipes` keys, but `recipes` itself appears to be undefined at that point:

```
const updateRecipe = Object.keys(recipes).map((recipe, sidx) => {
```

Maybe you meant this instead?:

```
const updateRecipe = Object.keys(this.state.recipes).map((recipe, sidx) => {
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is **not related to binding** with the correct context, but getting the data from recipes object in

```
value={this.props.recipes[id].title}
```

the id that you get from match.params.id may not be present in `this.props.recipes` and hence it returns undefined, you need to add a check

```
value={this.props.recipes[id].title? this.props.recipes[id].title: ''}
```